# Sprites and equipping sprite clothes in Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

How do I equip clothes to a sprite in Phaser? Say I use the following:

[image: http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/human_base.png]

[image: http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/16x18hair-clothingpack_preview2.png]

The only way I can think of is making a image with each sprite on. There must be a different way, like overlaying or something perhaps?

Comment: Wrong forum, a mod will correct that. But yes, you would overlay the "style" on the character. As long as the overlays are transparent, it would be fine. To optimize you could "cache" the character with the overlay applied. But again, wrong forum, and have no clue what Phaser is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check this project: https://github.com/makrohn/Universal-LPC-spritesheet.

And for the integration in Phaser, try Something like that:

```js
function preload() {
    game.load.spritesheet('female_body', 'sprites/body/female/light.png', 64, 64);
    game.load.spritesheet('female_hair', 'sprites/hair/female/pixie/blonde.png', 64, 64);
    game.load.spritesheet('female_torso', 'sprites/torso/tunics/female/teal_tunic.png', 64, 64);
    game.load.spritesheet('female_legs', 'sprites/legs/pants/female/teal_pants_female.png', 64, 64);
}

function create() {
    var group = game.add.group();
    group.add(game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'female_body', 13 * 9));
    group.add(game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'female_hair', 13 * 9));
    group.add(game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'female_torso', 13 * 9));
    group.add(game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'female_legs', 13 * 9));
    group.callAll('animations.add', 'animations', 'walk', Phaser.ArrayUtils.numberArrayStep(13 * 9, 13 * 9 + 9));
    group.callAll('animations.play', 'animations', 'walk', 9, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Phaser.Sprite#addChild`](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Sprite.html#addChild) to attach cloth sprites to your player sprite.

```
// Player sprite
var player = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'player-sprite');

// Cloth sprite
var cloth = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'cloth-sprite');

// Tweak anchor position to correctly align clothing over player 
cloth.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);

player.addChild(cloth);
```